# How can I format an html page so that when a link is added to G , it looks nice?

Tags: html, google-plus

Im building a new website, and I was testing the ability to add a "link" to google plus and have the article and it's content (summary) get pulled into google+.

When I do this today, all I see is an image - and no text.  I'm sure that there is some formatting change I can make to the page to make the text come in...  But I don't know what to do.

If there is a guide somewhere I would like to read it, but I cannot find one.  Thanks for the help

An example page:
http://alexedison.com/index.php?indexNum=8

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to create snippet data for your page. Google provides a tool for doing this as well as additional information at:

https://developers.google.com/+/web/snippet

You can validate the data on your page using the Google structured data testing tool:

https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem in your webpage.

Google Plus has change the look of each post.

now it shows only Image, Title along with given URL.

if you visit Google Plus , you can see posts without description meta information.